# Maui SetHasBackButton disables swipe navigation in iOS

Tags: ios, maui

In our app in Xamarin.Forms we were hiding back button by calling:

`NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton( this, false );`

This was hiding back button, so we could implement our own, but swipe back was still working in iOS.

If I do same in Maui it will also disables swipe back. Not sure if this is a bug and should file a report or was this change made on purpose?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```cs
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
#if IOS
        UIKit.UINavigationController? vc = Platform.GetCurrentUIViewController() as UIKit.UINavigationController;
        //using UIKit, find the UINavigationController
        if (vc != null)
        {
            vc.InteractivePopGestureRecognizer.Enabled = true;
        }
#endif
    }
```